# Time Capsule + Ubee Router?

Tags: networking, router, time-machine

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I recently had TWC installed in my house, and wanted to disable the NAT and router functions of it. I have a Time Capsule hooked up to it from LAN1 (on the Ubee) to the WAN port on the TC.

The problems started occurring here. I figured the settings would be these:

> **Ubee**
>
> - Configuration mode: Bridge
> - DHCP: Off
>
> **TC**
>
> - IPv4: 192.168.100.2
> - Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
> - Router Address: 192.168.100.1
> - DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
> - Router Mode: DHCP and NAT

But using those settings, my TC says "Double NAT", so I have to change it all around to the default settings of the Ubee using NAT.

This leads me to believe bridge mode doesn't actually turn off NAT...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. UBee is **NOT** in bridge mode. It is still in NAT mode. That is why your **TC Router Address** is still in 192.168.100.1, which is wrong.
2. Your ISP won't assign you a static IP (TWC does not) (1)
3. Your ISP *might* assign you a static IP. (2)

#### 1. Time Capsule

- Connect with AirPort Utility
- Click Internet tab,
- Connect Using: DHCP
- Update Time Capsule

#### 2. Time Capsule

- Connect with AirPort Utility
- Click Internet tab,
- Connect Using: Static
- Fill in IP and DNS information given by your ISP, or retrive from UBee if still available.

#### More Diagnostic Steps

Base on some ancient [post](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r24925861-TWC-Upgrade-to-TWC-wideband-resulted-in-downgrade-to-NAT-d-IP), Ubee has different level of login. To change connection mode use

```
<Modem IP>/TlModeChange.asp
```

If that does not work (or don't have the master password), you may need to call support.

#### Time Capsule

- Connect with AirPort Utility
- Click Internet tab,
- Connect Using: DHCP
- DHCP Servers: 8.8.8.8

Make sure the cable between Time Capsule and Ubee is plugin time Machine **WAN Port** (Port with a circle icon).

[image]

For **TC** to be NAT router and DHCP server:

- Connect with AirPort Utility
- Click Network tab,
- Router Mode: DHCP and NAT

All LAN (in-house) switch/hub/computers should be plug into **TC Ethernet Ports**. In other words, **TC** should be the **ONLY** device connected to **Ubee**. All other devices are connected to **TC Ethernet Ports**.

#### Additional Test

In the TC, there are a few tabs. In "NETWORK" tab, we should use "DHCP and NAT". In "INTERNET" tab, we should use DHCP, unless you have static IP from your ISP.

If those settings are correct, one thing you can try is to power off your TC, wait 10min, and power on again. Check "Router Address" is an internet address.

The next test you can try to ping 8.8.8.8 when your internet "goes out". If that ping works but you cannot surf the web, that means your ISP DHCP does not include DNS. That can be put in manually in "INTERNET" tab. Use 8.8.8.8 as DNS server, while keeping Connect Using: DHCP.

Comment: No, I put it into Bridge mode that way.

Comment: @Charlie Lets confirm you are able to access [this](http://www.dslreports.com/speak/slideshow/25262136?c=1612476&ret=L2ZvcnVtL3IyNDkyNTg2MS1UV0MtVXBncmFkZS10by1UV0Mtd2lkZWJhbmQtcmVzdWx0ZWQtaW4tZG93bmdyYWRlLXRvLU5BVC1kLUlQ) and select "Bridge Mode: Enable"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: double check TM setting and connection.

Comment: Yes, those are all the same. However I want the TC to handle NAT and DHCP.

Comment: Let me know if your network is configure and connected as I put it in my answer.

Comment: When using just DHCP, it either will connect for a little, then the internet will go out. Or it won't connect at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6757/discussion-between-john-siu-and-charlie)

Comment: I believe the problem was that the Time Capsule was not getting the IP address via DHCP from Time Warner, instead it was set to static. Calling TWC support fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. I should have ask to confirm static ip much earlier.

Comment: If you want to add that to the question, I'll mark it as accepted so people can find the solution quickly.